# call python script from flask_restful

Tags: python, flask-restful

I would like to call python script using flask_restful and I followed below link to implement
https://dev.to/aaahmedaa/create-restapi-for-your-python-scripts-using-flask-with-15-line-of-code-10ml

I execute the command python app.py from command prompt and passed image as input from browser as below
http://localhost:5000/ImageClassification/image1.jpg

I am getting output as {"data": null}

It suppose to get output as shown below from cnn_classification.py script, please let me know where I did mistake.

cnn_classification.py:

```
    import os
    import subprocess
    os.getcwd()
    os.chdir("D:/LH_data/LH_tensorflow/tensorflow-for-poets-2/")

    def lh_image_classification(input_image):
        subprocess.call(['python', '-m', 'scripts.label_image', '--graph=tf_files/optimized_graph.pb', '--image=' + input_image])
```

app.py:

```
    import cnn_classification
    from flask import Flask, request
    from flask_restful import Resource, Api
    from sys import argv

    app = Flask(__name__)
    api = Api(app)

    #input_image = argv[1]
    class imageClassification(Resource):
          def get(self, input_image):
              return {'data': cnn_classification.lh_image_classification(input_image)}

    api.add_resource(imageClassification, '/ImageClassification/<input_image>')

    if __name__ == '__main__':
         app.run()
```

Comment: Yes, your `lh_image_classification` does not return anything.

Comment: I edited my question, please check it

Comment: Ok, what you can do here is capture subprocess output, but I would personally first look into calling `scripts.label_image` from python directly rather via a subprocess

Answer (score 0):

You should not be calling subproccess the way you are doing most fundamentally because you are creating a security hole. A command could be passed to the endpoint you describe by making calling your endpoint with something like `/ImageClassification/image.png;sudo rm -rf /` or worse.

To begin with, use the script instead of using a subprocess. Details depend on what is inside `scripts.label_image` but I guess it should look something like

```
import scripts.label_image
from flask import Flask, request
from flask_restful import Resource, Api

app = Flask(__name__)
api = Api(app)

class ImageClassification(Resource):
    def get(self, input_image):
        result = label_image(
            graph="tf_files/optimized_graph.pb",
            image=input_image
        )
        return {'data': result}

api.add_resource(ImageClassification, '/ImageClassification/<input_image>')

if __name__ == '__main__':
     app.run()
```

this assumes that the script `label_image` is a function of the form

```
def label_image(graph, image):
    #... does stuff
    return result
```

You might have to move some stuff from `"D:/LH_data/LH_tensorflow/tensorflow-for-poets-2/"` to your project folder so be able to import it in your flask application.